# How to set the URL for View using Wagtail?

Tags: django, wagtail

> Does Wagtail only use the slug in Promote Tab, or should I set the url in
>   urls.py?

I'm using Wagtail, I've 2 pages:

**a) Ministerios Internacionales Elim**
**b) Doctrina Elim**

I want to set ***a*** as homepage, and ***b*** to:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/doctrina-elim/`

[image]

*Right now `doctrina/urls.py` is empty :(*

I've this model in `doctrina/models.py`:

```
class DoctrinaIndexPage(Page):

    template = 'doctrina/doctrina_index_page.html'

    nivel = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Básico')

    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Publicación reciente')

    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('subtitle', classname="full"),
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full")
    ]
```

*The view has this (doctrina/views.py)*:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home_page(response):
    return render(response, "home/home_page.html")


# Create your views here.
def doctrina_index_page(response):
    return render(response, "doctrina/doctrina_index_page.html")
```

In `promote tab`, it has this url:

```
doctrina-elim
```

But entering that after the hostname gives 404, why?

[image]

Structure:

```
-doctrina
    |__pycache.py_
    |__migrations.py
    |__templates
    |___init__.py
    |_admin.py
    |_apps.py
    |_models.py
    |_test.py
    |_urls.py
    |_views.py

-elim
     |__pycache_.py
     |_settings.py
     |_static
     |_templates
     |___init__.py
     |_urls.py
     |_wsgi.py
-home
     |__pycache_.py
     |_migrations.py
     |_static
     |_templates \ home
        |_home_page.html
        |_welcome_page.html
     |___init__.py 
     |_models.py
     |_urls.py
     |_views.py
```

I can only access my Page models when setting them as sites, and visit the "/" home.

Answer (score 1):

With Wagtail you will likely find that your `views.py` file does not have a lot in it.  Rather, you create links to navigate to the page, and then Wagtail serves up the page - you don't have to render it from a view as you are doing.  Here is some example code of how you might render a navigation bar:

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

<ul>
    {% for item in request.site.root_page.get_children.live.in_menu %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% pageurl item %}">{{ item.title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This code only shows a single-level menu/page tree (not sub-menus), and it doesn't show applying a class name to indicate the active menu item - it only shows the basics of creating a menu.  To conclude:  whereas in Django you render and create associated context from within `views.py`, Wagtail takes care of rendering the page without the need of anything in `views.py`.  However, if you need to add context to a Wagtail page, then define `get_context(self, request)` for the page:  https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/topics/pages.html#customising-template-context.

Comment: I see, may you tell me from where do you get the `pageurl` variable? I just copied your code to my navbar.html, and got: `TemplateSyntaxError at /
Invalid block tag on line 16: 'pageurl', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned at [How to set the URL for View using Wagtail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62034144/how-to-set-the-url-for-view-using-wagtail) , the `doctrina-elim` page needs to be made a CHILD page of the homepage.

You can do that from the page listing ([this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHbQG.png)) by clicking on 'More' underneath the page, then 'Move'.

If you don't do that, Wagtail will not treat it as belonging to the same site.